# c++ Expression must be a modifiable lvalue int sum

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that has a for loop inside it which adds an array together and then outside of the for loop i want to take the sum of the array and divide it by 12 and place that number in a variable to return to my main cpp file.

Here is my code

```
    int sum = 0;
for (int counting = 0; counting < 15; counting++)
{
    sum += m[counting];

}

sum / 12 = cost;



return cost;
```

The line i'm getting my error on is `sum / 12 = cost;`
sum is highlighted red and says "Expression must be a modifiable lvalue" Now I did some searching(not a lot of time atm) on google and here on stackoverflow and cannot find a solution that is similar to mine so I can understand why its wrong and fix it.

Would anyone be able to help me understand what is wrong here so I am able to fix it?

Comment: What do you expect `sum / 12 = cost;` to do?  If you are trying to assign to `cost` why would you do it backwards of the two previous assignments?

Comment: I expect it to take the sum and divide it by 12 and then store that number in cost so that I can return it

Comment: remember assignment is always assign what is on the right hand side to the left hand side.

Comment: @saviro but why then isnt it `m[counting] += sum` but the other way around?

Comment: OH I have it backwards, that makes a whole lot of sense now.. Thanks guys!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Apologies for asking this question, I will not let it happen again. I shouldn't have made such a mistake in the first place and will not make this same mistake again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simply LValue must be modifiable. you cannot assign a value to an expression:

```
sum / 12 = cost; // (sum / 12) is an expression.
```

Comment: It's not a constant, but it's an expression that doesn't refer to a location, but rather performs a calculation.

Comment: Now you've edited it to "mustn't be modifiable" when it's the opposite.